# Transparent gui Shows another gui when it is not supposed to?

Tags: gui, roblox

I am making a game in roblox. and in that game i need a Main-menu. and the main-menu gui is basically transparent and there is more guis behind in another `ScreenGui` those gui's are not supposed to show until the main menu is turned off. I have a post on `Scriptinghelpers.org` about this and it seems nobody knows the answer. My Post: https://scriptinghelpers.org/questions/117430/object-transparency-showing-not-what-its-not-supposed-to

Answer (score 1):

This is because Gui's stack on top of each other and other Gui objects (`Frames`, `TextButtons`, etc) can bleed through them if the top Gui has Transparent layers/parts.

To fix this just set the `Enabled` value to false for all the other Gui's and set it to true once the main Gui is disabled.

Comment: i would like to show the first gui and i still want to show the second gui

Comment: @PyCoder64 I don't quite understand what you mean then. It'd be good if you could expand on what you mean.

Comment: imagine you add two Frames one transparent and another one that is not. and you make the transparent one so it is full screen and my Question is you can see the Frame that is not transparent is it possible to show the transparent gui and still keep the other one but not show it?

Comment: @PyCoder64 I still don't quite understand what you mean. Could you be more specific on this? Maybe give me an example or tell me what you're trying to code?

Comment: This is more of a theory than  a coding thing